# azure Blob MD5 checksum and local MD5 checksum not matching

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, md5sum

my file test.txt contains

```
checksum test file
```

when I upload into blob its md5 is

> CONTENT-MD5   cvL65GNcvWFoqZUTI5oscw==

when I run in local `md5Sum test.txt` its value is

> 72f2fae4635cbd6168a99513239a2c73

Comment: tried encoding to base64 also but still not matching. Same issue with all the files

Comment: check this one https://galdin.dev/blog/md5-has-checks-on-azure-blob-storage-files/

Comment: Thanks @silent. It helped me a lot.

Comment: great! I made an answer out of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments. Solution from [here](https://galdin.dev/blog/md5-has-checks-on-azure-blob-storage-files/):

> Googled around and found a suggestion to use openssl dgst, and it
> worked!
>
> `openssl dgst -md5 -binary $filename | base64`
>
> Turns out, md5sum returns a hex representation of the hash and I had
> to unhex it before computing its base64:
>
> `md5sum --binary $filename | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -p -r | base64`