# Compare files uploaded to Azure Blob with on-prem

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently uploading files to an Azure blob via a scheduled Powershell script.  Is there any way that I can do a check to make sure that the files have uploaded successfully?  I am writing to a log file, but I want to delete the files that have uploaded from my on-prem storage after the upload.

The files have unique names.  Is there any way I can do a compare > create file on-prem after successful compare?  I'd then be able to create a script that would only delete the files if this file existed.

Thanks.

Comment: you can check the md5 hashes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63375981/azure-blob-md5-checksum-and-local-md5-checksum-not-matching/63376858#63376858

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.  I want this to be automated, so I need to trust it to run, create a file based on them matching and then delete the local copies.  It'll only be uploading a few files a day.

Answer (score 1):

After upload of on-prem files with Azure Storage blob, you can list the blobs in the Azure Storage account and compare the file names with the On-prem files

If the file exists, you can delete the on-prem file

To list the blobs in an Azure Storage container, you can use the below command:

```
az storage blob list -c containerName --account-name storageAccountName
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't see the connection with how this would just look at the files just uploaded compared with what is on prem, and then delete them.  I could run a separate task to delete the files from local storage, but I'm still just basically accepting that the file uploaded without proof.  I'm not really sure what I want is possible without having a program do the upload, compare, delete.

Comment: If you want to compare the content inside the file, you can check the md5 hashes of the files

Comment: You might need to add the --access-key value ie. 
az storage blob list -c "<container-name>" --account-key "<account-key>" --account-name "<account-name>" --query 'length(@")"' -o table